# Android app so I'm not using my mobile data at home

Tags: android, automation, wifi

I keep forgetting to turn my mobile data off, and Wi-Fi on when I get home.

(The reason I turn my Wi-Fi off, is because when I'm walking about in town, if I leave Wi-Fi on, the phone keeps trying to connect to all the free Wi-Fis that usually require an in-browser sign in, or are just slow.)

Is there an app that will either automatically turn it off, or remind me, when it knows that I'm home?

Comment: My Android 4.1.2 *usually* switches to WiFi when available, does yours do that too?

Comment: And mine has a built in app to limit usage. It also has a warning, which I set at 80% of my monthly limit. After that, I am much more careful how I browse & set it to shut off at 95% usage. Isn't that built-in for you? Look in Settings ...

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! What do you mean by "at home"? Do you mean the location (GPS) or availability of your wifi or a specific time of the day (e.G. when you are not working)? "at Home" is difficult as a technical concept :)

Comment: @NicolasRaoul - Yes, I can do that. But the problem is, when I'm travelling through town, there's all these free wifis that it keeps switching too and getting interrupted by. So IO usually turn the wifi off.

Comment: @Mawg - Not a good solution. If I get home and youtube 80% of my data in one night, doesn't really suit me for the rest of the month.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's available on all Androids but my LG G4 has "smart settings" that allow Wi-Fi and Bluetooth (as well as vibrate/sound) to be automatically enabled or disabled when "at home".

Answer (score 2):

There are many [Automation apps](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_automation) to achieve what you want – and more. There are even single-purpose app exactly for that: [Automatically activate/deactivate WiFi](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_wifi_automation#group_430). So depending on whether you want "just that" – or think of "starting with this, and then see what else is possible", recommendations might differ.

To make a good choice, some background first: How can be determinded that you are "home" (or wherever) and WiFi should be enabled (which assumes it's disabled)?

- GPS position: very accurate, but expensive to the battery
- network position: average accuracy, less battery-hungry, quite adequate for what you want
- CellID based position: most friendly to your battery, quite adequate for your use-case – but needs some training (you will have to "calibrate", i.e. let the app know what CellIDs you consider being "home"). Another plus of that: No network required for it to work.

I'd recommend the last variant, if you don't mind the "initial training". That's what I use myself for years, and it works great – though from time to time, I've to run another "scan" (as the provider installed new cells and removed old ones).

---

So now, let's see for available solutions:

**[Smart WiFi Toggler](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sebouh00.smartwifitoggler)** would be a single-purpose app for your case. It learns your preferred hotspots by recording their network positions (network-based and CellIDs) whenever you connect to them, so there's no manual training required. A nice addition is it even "hops over" to a stronger AP – when there's one available you've used in the past. And has some other interesting WiFi-related features you might value.

[image: screenshot] [image: screenshot] [image: screenshot]
<sup>*Smart WiFi Toggler* (source: [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sebouh00.smartwifitoggler); click images for larger variants)</sup>

As the first and third screenshots show, *Smart WiFi Toggler* uses CellIDs to "mark" positions of known hotspots used by you. As long as you're not in airplane mode, that means no additional energy is required for location – as your phone already knows which cell tower it is connected to. So this is very efficient.

---

From the multi-purpose automation apps, let me name **[Llama](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kebab.Llama)**. *Llama* not only can deal with your WiFi, but with many more things. It can act on events like location, time, battery level, calendar events, and more – and apply actions to networks (such as toggle WiFi or mobile data), screen brightness, audio profiles, and many other things.

---

The most powerful tool, though, would be **[Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm)** – which is what I use. Other than above mentioned tools, this is a paid app (but has a 7 day trial available at their website) – but you could even have it cook coffee, so to speak. For details on this, take a look at my [collection of Tasker resources](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/resources_tasker), or at the [tasker tag-wiki on our sister site](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/tasker/info). It would be too much to go into detail on this app – but as said, that's what I use to

- disable WiFi when I leave home, and enable it when being back home
- put the device into "silent mode" with the clock on when docked at night
- push up the display timeout to 5 minutes when using my RSS reader (or other reading apps), but returning to a 30s timeout when not
- lower the ringer volume when in the office

and many more nice things :)

Comment: Reading your question again, you didn't explicitely mention WiFi. I've implicated this here nevertheless, as that's the most likely reason for "turning mobile data off at home". If WiFi is *not* involved, *Llama* and *Tasker* still apply as solutions: both can turn mobile data off as well.